# Windows restore position sometimes doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows, position, window-position, setwindowpos

I wrote a simple C# program that saves the locations and sizes of open windows to a file, and then can also restore them from that file (based on command-line arguments). This always works for some programs and not for others, and I don't know why.

The part that gets window position (x,y) and size (w,h) uses this standard Windows function

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = GetWindowPlacement(windowCaption);
```

The part that sets a window's size and position uses this standard Windows function

```
SetWindowPos(target_hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, wi.x, wi.y, wi.w, wi.h, 0);
```

These are declared in the code like so

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd,
    IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);
```

The rest of the code is unremarkable: save some data to a text file, read some data from a text file. All of it is copy-pasted from online examples, and I am a novice C# / Windows programmer.

The program works quite well on certain programs and not at all on others. I can restore Chrome to its size and position, but not Firefox, and not Microsoft Edge. Visual Studio Code works, but not R Studio. This is a surprise to me, because (not knowing much about Windows programming) I expected that the GUI part of any Windows program was coded with standard Windows libraries, and so any program that works on Windows would respond to `SetWindowPos` the same way.

Why does this work for some programs and not for others?

I need to do this because I have a 4K monitor, and somehow Windows loses the size and position of most windows every time the monitor is turned off or times out. I posted separately about this, got no solution, so I wrote my own, which mostly works.
https://superuser.com/questions/1513288/windows-loses-window-position-on-large-monitor

If anyone is interested, the source code is at
https://github.com/radumanolescu/WinPos

Running Windows 10 Pro, fully patched, on a 2019 PC with solid specs.